# How to read a json file into a Map

Tags: json, go

I have a json file like this - data.json

```
{
    "data1" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag1",
        "info" : "some_info1",
    },
     "data2" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag2",
        "info" : "some_info2",
    }
}
```

I have a struct like below

```
type someStruct struct {
    tag    string `json:"tag"`
    info   string `json:"info"`

}
```

I am trying to read json file into below map

```
errorJSON    map[string]someStruct
```

Below is my code

```
jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(data.json)
err := jsonParser.Decode(&errorJSON)
```

But I am getting a error

```
json.UnmarshalTypeError
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Although not the cause of that specific error, if you keep your fields unexported you won't be able to unmarshal anything into them. (https://play.golang.com/p/FE_Z8Y6XFAK)

Comment: Your fields must be exported *and* your JSON must be valid. As quoted it contains syntax errors.

Comment: `someStruct` fields must be exported, the JSON must be valid, and include what type that `data` var is, because `data.json` might not be valid

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the data.  It is not valid JSON as it has trailing commas.

Try with this:

```
{
    "data1" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag1",
        "info" : "some_info1"
    },
     "data2" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag2",
        "info" : "some_info2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must uppercase `someStruct` fields and json must valid format.

```
type someStruct struct {
    Tag  string `json:"tag"`
    Info string `json:"info"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example json has extra commas - removed

The data structure is a pair of your someStruct with keys, so needs to be a map

uppercase the json struct fields

Here is a working example based on your code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type someStruct struct {
    Tag  string `json:"tag"`
    Info string `json:"info"`
}

func main() {
    buf := `{
    "data1" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag1",
        "info" : "some_info1"
    },
     "data2" : {
        "tag" : "some_tag2",
        "info" : "some_info2"
    }
}`

    dat := make(map[string]someStruct)

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(buf), &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", dat)
}
```

playground https://play.golang.org/p/ZGuCcGI3vA6